# Change default from address from Postfix from www-data to something else

Tags: apache-2.2, php, postfix, sendmail

Setting up Postfix and Apache/PHP on an Ubuntu server.  Mail's now going out ok with the proper domain name, but the local part display name is always "www-data" as I'm assuming Postfix uses the name of the user by default.

In the php.ini file, I was able to change the `sendmail_path` to `sendmail_path = "/usr/sbin/sendmail -t -i -f support@example.com"` but the email display name still appears as www-data .  I tried specifying the display name a few different ways but that was ignored and the mail still went out as www-data.

What I'd like to be able to do is by default, have any mail with missing from, return-path, etc. headers go out as `"Example Support" <support@example.com>`, but I'm not sure if that's possible.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As I understand the question, you're trying to set the full name of the sender, not the address (or, in addition to the address). In general, Postfix doesn't care what that is, and you set it when your MUA (in this case, some php script) generates the message headers. I'm not familiar with coding in php, but it looks like this is explained in the documentation for the [PHP mail() function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php).

But if you're calling out to postfix's `sendmail` binary to send the message, you can use `-F "Support System"` to do what you want. Maybe this will have to be in the `mail.force_extra_parameters` setting — I'm not so clear on how php works here. (Mostly, that's the wrong thing to do anyways.)

Comment: This works well, thank you.  I usually set the headers properly when sending out through PHP mail(), etc. but wanted to set something as the default in case the headers were incorrect, etc.

Comment: Note you can use BOTH the -f and -F options to set display name and address. For example: -F "Support System" -f "support@example.com"

Answer (score 15):

Add in your main.cf

```
smtp_generic_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/generic
```

And create a file named /etc/postfix/generic with :

```
www-data support@example.com
```

run `postmap /etc/postfix/generic` to compile and reload postfix.
Your send name is now support@example.com

Comment: This had no effect.

Comment: do you reload postfix ? Maybe restart. Do you have errors in your logs ?

Comment: Does this also work for setting the return-path when the MUA is PHPmailer and PHPmailer is using `mail()`?

Comment: @Dom, the return-path has changed as expected and I got all pass SPF, DKIM & DMARC but still ending up in Junk Box!  Please help.

Comment: The spam detection is depending of hundred of factors. Your mail may not be valid too (and not only the sender)

Answer (score 5):

You should do one last thing to complete process which is @Dom has forgetten. Run the following command :

`$ postmap /etc/postfix/generic`

This command will be create `generic.db` file inside the /postfix directory.

If you don't do this, you can face of the following error output :

`fatal: open database /etc/postfix/generic.db: No such file or directory`

Comment: Does this also work for setting the return-path when the MUA is PHPmailer and PHPmailer is using `mail()`?

Answer (score -1):

try this

/etc/apache2/envvars

User ${APACHE_RUN_USER}
Group ${APACHE_RUN_GROUP}

Comment: How is that supposed to fix anything?

Comment: oh sorry 
this part was missing.. 

on the envars file 
lookfor this 
export APACHE_RUN_USER=www-data
export APACHE_RUN_GROUP=www-data

and change it to this 

export APACHE_RUN_USER=info
export APACHE_RUN_GROUP=www-data