# Sendmail doesn't use aliases

Tags: linux, email, sendmail

I'm trying to forward emails sent from the host to root to address `admin@test.com`.

I've checked that alias file is being read:

```
[root@localhost etc]# sendmail -d27.2 -bv root
alias(root)
root (, root) aliased to admin@test.com
self_reference(admin@test.com)
...no self ref
admin@test.com... deliverable: mailer relay, host smtp.test.com, user admin@test.com
```

But the email is still beeing sent to `root@localhost.test.com`:

```
[root@localhost etc]# (echo Subject: test; echo) | sendmail -v root
root... Connecting to smtp.test.com. via relay...
220 smtp.test.com ESMTP
EHLO localhost.test.com
250-smtp.test.com
250-PIPELINING
250-SIZE 10240000
250-VRFY
250-ETRN
250-STARTTLS
250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
250-8BITMIME
250 DSN
STARTTLS
220 2.0.0 Ready to start TLS
EHLO localhost.test.com
250-smtp.test.com
250-PIPELINING
250-SIZE 10240000
250-VRFY
250-ETRN
250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
250-8BITMIME
250 DSN
MAIL From:root@localhost.test.com SIZE=15
250 2.1.0 Ok
RCPT To:root@localhost.test.com
DATA
250 2.1.5 Ok
354 End data with <CR><LF>.<CR><LF>
.
250 2.0.0 Ok: queued as F381570F1
root... Sent (Ok: queued as F381570F1)
Closing connection to smtp.test.com
QUIT
221 2.0.0 Bye
```

May be somebody knows what can be the issue?

Comment: sendmail is pretty limited, why not install postfix (which will install a sendmail wrapper) and use generic maps? http://serverfault.com/questions/209713/change-default-from-address-from-postfix-from-www-data-to-something-else/424127#424127

Answer (score 1):

Sendmail (by sendmail.org) applies aliases **after** delivery to local sendmail daemon listening at `127.0.0.1:25`.

Have you checked where the message is delivered in log files or the recipients' mailboxes?

Comment: Message is actually getting delivered to the mail relay with following addresses: From:root@localhost.test.com To:root@localhost.test.com and then it's getting bounced because relay cannot deliver it to root@localhost.test.com

Comment: Could you post results produced by the two command below? `echo '$j'| sendmail -Ac -bt`, `echo '$j' | sendmail -Am -bt` [the second one should be executed by `root`]

Comment: `[root@localhost ~]# echo '$j'| sendmail -Ac -bt
ADDRESS TEST MODE (ruleset 3 NOT automatically invoked)
Enter <ruleset> <address>
localhost.test.com`


`[root@localhost ~]#
[root@localhost ~]# echo '$j' | sendmail -Am -bt
ADDRESS TEST MODE (ruleset 3 NOT automatically invoked)
Enter <ruleset> <address>
localhost.test.com`

Comment: It seems that you sendmail ignores aliases for localhost.test.com domain.  The following test may provide hints why : `echo '3,0 root@localhost.test.com' | sendmail -Am -bt`

Comment: canonify input: root @ localhost . test . com  
Canonify2 input: root < @ localhost . test . com >  
Canonify2 returns: root < @ localhost . test . com . >  
canonify returns: root < @ localhost . test . com . >  
parse input: root < @ localhost . test . com . >  
Parse0 input: root < @ localhost . test . com . >  
Parse0 returns: root < @ localhost . test . com . > 
ParseLocal input: root < @ localhost . test . com . > 
ParseLocal returns: root < @ localhost . test . com . > 
Parse1 input: root < @ localhost . test . com . > 
Parse1 returns: $# local $: root  parse returns: $# local $: root

Comment: Previous comment is the output from echo '3,0 root@localhost.test.com' | sendmail -Am -bt. I'm not sure how if it helps

Comment: the thing is that when I don "[root@localhost etc]# sendmail -d27.2 -bv root" it doesn't ignore aliases

Comment: What is returned by `sendmail -d27.2 -bv root@localhost.test.com`?  You seem to use "strange and unusual" sendmail configuration.

Comment: [root@localhost ~]# sendmail -d27.2 -bv root@localhost.test.com
alias(root)
root@localhost.test.com (, root) aliased to admin@test.com
self_reference(admin@test.com)
 ... no self ref
admin@test.com
 ... deliverable: mailer relay, host smtp.test.com, user admin@test.com

Comment: Sorry, it seems to be beyond a simple answer.